# ImportError: No module named 'jsonconv'

Tags: python, json2html

I am running **Python 3.4**

Did pip install json2html with no errors.

However, when I execute "import json2html" I got:

```
>>> import json2html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\json2html-0.3-py3.4.egg\json2html\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'jsonconv'
>>>
```

please help suggest..

Comment: looks like it is not python3 compatible see here : https://github.com/softvar/json2html/issues/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this library is not python3-compatible.

Error was caused by this line in the __init__.py file:

```
from jsonconv import *
```

While, instead, it should be:

```
from .jsonconv import *
```

Try this fork instead: https://github.com/YAmikep/json2html

Comment: where is the auto generated html get saved? can we assign path?